# Setting CAEmitterLayer properties with KVC

Tags: ios, particle-system, kvc, caemitterlayer

I am attempting to to change properties on a CAEmitterLayer instance dynamically.  I am making a call to setValue:forKey: like this: `[self.mainViewController.mainView.spaceView.emitterLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0] forKey:@"emitterCells.particle.velocityRange"];`  but I am not seeing any change in the particle emitter.  If i set that property to 0 by hard coding it no particles are emitted.  [Here](https://gist.github.com/AlexanderBollbach/90fd2e7065a8aeb3c243) is a link to a gist file containing the UIView that implements the particle system.  I know KVC can be tricky with miss typing something so maybe I'm simply over-looking something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

> so maybe I'm simply over-looking something obvious

Indeed. The problem is this line:

```
setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0] forKey:@"emitterCells.particle.velocityRange"
```

The string `"emitterCells.particle.velocityRange"` is not a key.

It is a *key path*. You need to call `setValue:forKeyPath:`.